# Making a function and calling two different results from it. How do I do that

Tags: python, html, function

I am trying to check the balance of a match equation. The code below is what I have currently.

```
#Creating the math equation the use check_html on.
e = "10 - (3 + (2+1)*8)" 
 def check_html(html_string):   
d = Stack()
balanced = True
for symbol in html_string: 
if symbol == "(":
    d.push(symbol)
elif symbol == ")":
    if d.is_empty():
        balanced = False
    else:
        d.pop()

if not d.is_empty:
balanced = False
str1 = "10 - (3 + (2+1)*8)"
str2 = "10 - (3 + (2+1)*8))"
print ("is the first valid?", check_html(str1))
print ("is the second valid?", check_html(str2))
print("Is it balanced? ", balanced)
```

The output of this code is

```
is the first valid? None
is the second valid? None
Is it balanced?  True
```

It should say the first is TRUE and the second is FALSE. What am I doing incorrect now.

Comment: Your question is not very clear
Also can you adjust the indentation for your program.

Comment: I am confused by the wording of you question. Can you give us an example of your sample output? Do you want to call check_html(html_string) with 2 different strings?

Comment: Looks so obvious. If I understand the question correctly, can you not call the function twice.

Comment: inside function you should use `html_string` instead of `e` in line `for symbol in e:` and then you can run `check_html(e)` and `check_html("wrong text")` BTW: You should also create and use `d = Stack()` inside function.

Comment: @BarunSharma I updated the question.

Comment: @Sri Question updated

Comment: instead of writing "print("Is it balanced? ", balanced)" in the end...write "return balanced"

Comment: You should put the stack initialization in the function. And as @furas said, you loop over e, not the parameter you passed in

Comment: What is the purpose of the argument `html_string`?

Comment: always put code with correct indentations. Question is useless if code has wrong indentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `html_string` instead of `e` in line

```
for symbol in html_string:  # `html_string` instead` of `e`
```

That's all.

---

**BTW:** it would be good to create and use `Stack()` inside function - so it will create new empty stack when you run function with new string.

---

**EDIT:** Full function

```
# --- functions ---

def check_html(html_string):
    d = Stack()

    balanced = True

    for symbol in html_string: 
        if symbol == "(":
            d.push(symbol)
        elif symbol == ")":
            if d.is_empty():
                balanced = False
            else:
               d.pop()

    if not d.is_empty(): # you forgot `()
        balanced = False

    print("Is it balanced? ", balanced)

# --- main ---

e = "10 - (3 + (2+1)*8)"
check_html(e)
check_html( e+')' )
```

---

If you want to use `check_html()` in `print()` then function you should use `return balanced` instead `of print()`

```
# --- functions ---

def check_html(html_string):
    d = Stack()

    balanced = True

    for symbol in html_string: 
        if symbol == "(":
            d.push(symbol)
        elif symbol == ")":
            if d.is_empty():
                balanced = False
            else:
               d.pop()

    if not d.is_empty(): # you forgot `()
        balanced = False

    return balanced

# --- main ---

e = "10 - (3 + (2+1)*8)"
print("Is it balanced? ", check_html(e) )
print("Is it balanced? ", check_html( e+')' ) )
```

---

**EDIT:** full working example with own class `Stack`

```
# --- classes ---

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.data.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.data.pop(-1)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.data) == 0


# --- functions ---

def check_html(html_string):
    d = Stack()

    balanced = True

    for symbol in html_string: 
        if symbol == "(":
            d.push(symbol)
        elif symbol == ")":
            if d.is_empty():
                balanced = False
            else:
                d.pop()

    if not d.is_empty(): # you forgot `()
        balanced = False

    return balanced

# --- main ---

e = "10 - (3 + (2+1)*8)"
print("Is it balanced?", check_html(e) )

#print("Is it balanced?", check_html(e + ')') )
f = e + ')'
print("Is it balanced?", check_html(f) )

#print("Is it balanced?", check_html('('+e+')') )
f = '(' + e + ')'
print("Is it balanced?", check_html(f) )

#print("Is it balanced?", check_html('('+e) )
f = '(' + e
print("Is it balanced?", check_html(f) )
```

Comment: I updated the code above by replace the e with html_string and moving the def check_html(html_string): above everything. When I change the equation to be incorrect how can I get the output to say false instead of true like its doing now.

Comment: run it as before `check_html(e)` or directly `check_html("10 - (3 + (2+1)*8))")` or `check_html("some wrong equation")`

Comment: BTW: there is no need to put `check_html("some wrong equation")` inside `print()` - `print(.. check_html(...))` - because `check_html` uses own `print()` to display result and it returns `None` which `print(... check_html(...))` will display. If you want to use `print( ..., check_html(...))` then inside function you should use `return "Is it balanced? " + str(balanced)` or at least `return balanced` instead of `print()`

Comment: BTW: don't move `e = ..` inside function. Keep `e = ... ` ouside function. When you run `check_html(e)` then it assign `html_string = e` and when function runs `for symbol in html_string` then it get symbol from value which was in `e`

Comment: Ok I moved the   e = "10 - (3 + (2+1)*8)"  back above the function and kept the d = stack() in it. I am updating my code now for the last issue I am having thanks.

Comment: I added example code. But I don't have `Stack` to test it.

Comment: if you put code in question then use correct indentations. Indentations are very important in Python and wrong indentation can change everything and code may not work as expected.

Comment: Yes I know I have to work on the indentation issues I have I am still very new. When I run the code with Print I get error saying return is outside function what does that mean

Comment: it can means you have wrong indentations - and Python doesn't know what to do with `return` which seems is not inside function - but `return` can be use only inside function.

Comment: to test my code I created own class Stack and now I put it all code in answer.

Comment: I knew indentation was super important but since I just started I still didn't think much about when coding. I just went through and fixed all of the indentations and it works so much better now. I really do appreciate you helping me out with this and being patient with me being so new. I will put you as the correct answer and have a great day.